Sci-Fi channel flick about abandoned desert town overtaken by coyotes/wolves in human skin
I remember watching this movie a long time ago. It was probably a low budget, typical Sci-Fi channel TV-only movie. These people are pulled over by a cop driving in a desert, and they are taken to a police station. The cop coughs blood up while they are driving which they find strange. They escape the police station somehow and try to escape. The town's entirely deserted. At one point they enter a building where a lady pulls a lever on a slot machine and blood comes out of it instead of coins. The humans in this town are actually coyotes/wolves in disguise, and the fake cop/sheriff is their leader, evidenced by how they follow him. The residents of this town were killed for their skin disguises. That is pretty much all I remember about this movie. Does anyone have an idea what movie this is?

What do you consider "a long time ago?" 1950s? 70s? 90s? etc.

Sorry about that. I assumed that the sci fi channel was most associated with early 2000s. Probably should havd added the year.

This is Desperation, the 2006 movie adaptation of the Stephen King's novel of the same name from 1996.
The movie begins with a weird cop arresting people for made up reasons in the desert and bringing them to jail in a wild animals infested town where everyone is dead.
The cop looks severely ill and coughs blood from time to time.

Thanks! That was it!
